# How to deal with query strings before and after the hash in Angular

Tags: angularjs, query-string

I am using Angular v1.4.2

I am currently dealing with a query string that looks like this:

http://localhost/myProject/apply/?A=100&B=ABC&C=Test#/step1?D=3&E=X1&F=1

So that means that A, B and C are declared before the hash
D, E and F are declared after the hash

I cannot change this URL because it is generated by an external API and there is also a reason why the URL needs to be like this.

I have been trying to find ways to read all the parameters. Things I tried so far:

`$location.search();` returns only `{D, E, F}`

Ideally `$location.search();` should return `{A,B, C, D, E, F}`

One of the solutions suggests to change the location provider settings . Mine are these:

```
function $LocationProvider() {
  var hashPrefix = '',
      html5Mode = {
        enabled: false,
        requireBase: true,
        rewriteLinks: true
      };
```

Changing these settings to this:

```
function $LocationProvider() {
  var hashPrefix = '',
      html5Mode = {
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false,
        rewriteLinks: false
      };
```

did not fix anything and anyway for a project this size I don't want to mess with these settings.

Is there a way to read all query string parameters?

Comment: Can't see the example of how you need the link to look

Comment: Use you know, old school BOM: `location.search`, no `$`, no `()`. Plain ole JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: Rani, I don't want the link to look any different.
I want to read the query string parameters from the controller. The link can stay as it is

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this. If there is a better way, I'd like to know

Created a factory that reads all the parameters on the left.
At this point it was impossible to read the parameters on the right.

```
   export class QueryStringFactory {

        static $inject = ["$window", "$location"];

        private window: ng.IWindowService;
        private location: angular.ILocationService;

        constructor(public $window: ng.IWindowService, public $location: angular.ILocationService) {
            this.window = $window;
            this.location = $location;
        }

        searchLeft() {
            var left = window.location.search
                .split(/[&||?]/)
                .filter((x) => { return x.indexOf("=") > -1; })
                .map((x) => { return x.split(/=/); })
                .map((x) => {
                    x[1] = x[1].replace(/\+/g, " ");
                    return x;
                })
                .reduce((acc, current) => {
                    acc[current[0]] = current[1];
                    return acc;
                }, {});
            return left;
        }

        static factory() {
            var instance = ($window: ng.IWindowService, $location: angular.ILocationService) =>
                new QueryStringFactory($window, $location);
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Register the factory:

```
angular.factory("QueryStringFactory", Utils.QueryStringFactory.factory());
```

And use it in the controller like this:

```
    constructor(public $window: angular.IWindowService | any,
        public $location: angular.ILocationService, public queryString: Utils.QueryStringFactory) {

        var qsParamsRight = $location.search();
        var qsParamsLeft = queryString.searchLeft();
        var qsAllParams = $.extend(true, {}, qsParamsLeft, qsParamsRight);
    });
```